# get keys from nested dict JSON without hardcode the middle keys

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

Want to get the MetaEntry data from the dictionary, but each time the keys differ with some random names.

for example: `['Client']`

```
dictionary = {
    "Tags":[],
    "ObjectId":
    "ab9c6448-85fe-eb11-b563-281878c3a7fe",
    "Client": {
        "MetaData": {
            "MetaEntry": [
                {
                    "Key": "status",
                    "Value": "Active"
                    },
                {
                    "Key": "first_day_of_week",
                    "Value": "Monday"
                    },
                {
                    "Key": "default_induction_expiry",
                    "Value": "0"
                    }
                ]
            },
        "RelatedLinks": [],
        "Tags": [],
        "ObjectId": "6cf54386-d81a-eb11-9fb4-281878b13795",
        "Type": "Artifice.Web.Data.Entities.Client",
        "Name": "Amco Logictics "
        }
    }
```

print(dictionary['Client']['MetaData']['MetaEntry'])

here `['Client']` key will change randomly, so my above print fun will not work,  is there a workaround way to get the `['MetaData']['MetaEntry']` without hardcoding the `['Client']` key?

Comment: look at json path - https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have deeply nested dictionary, you can recursively traverse it to find all `MetaEntry` keys:

```py
dictionary = {
    "Tags": [],
    "ObjectId": "ab9c6448-85fe-eb11-b563-281878c3a7fe",
    "Client": {
        "MetaData": {
            "MetaEntry": [
                {"Key": "status", "Value": "Active"},
                {"Key": "first_day_of_week", "Value": "Monday"},
                {"Key": "default_induction_expiry", "Value": "0"},
            ]
        },
        "RelatedLinks": [],
        "Tags": [],
        "ObjectId": "6cf54386-d81a-eb11-9fb4-281878b13795",
        "Type": "Artifice.Web.Data.Entities.Client",
        "Name": "Amco Logictics ",
    },
}


def find(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if "MetaEntry" in d:
            yield d["MetaEntry"]
        else:
            for k, v in d.items():
                yield from find(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from find(v)


for meta_entry in find(dictionary):
    print(meta_entry)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"Key": "status", "Value": "Active"},
    {"Key": "first_day_of_week", "Value": "Monday"},
    {"Key": "default_induction_expiry", "Value": "0"},
]
```

---

EDIT: To print current path:

```py
def find(d, cur_path=None):
    if cur_path is None:
        cur_path = []

    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if "MetaEntry" in d:
            yield d["MetaEntry"], cur_path + ["MetaEntry"]
        else:
            for k, v in d.items():
                yield from find(v, cur_path + [k])
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i, v in enumerate(d):
            yield from find(v, cur_path + [i])


for meta_entry, cur_path in find(dictionary):
    print(cur_path)
    print(meta_entry)
```

Prints:

```
['Client', 'MetaData', 'MetaEntry']

[{'Key': 'status', 'Value': 'Active'}, {'Key': 'first_day_of_week', 'Value': 'Monday'}, {'Key': 'default_induction_expiry', 'Value': '0'}]
```

Comment: is there a way to get the Keys-path in this function , for example: dictionary['Client']['MetaData']['MetaEntry']. like this

Answer (score 2):

the below code will handle the situation where 'Client' will be replaced by other string

```
data = {"Tags": [], "ObjectId": "ab9c6448-85fe-eb11-b563-281878c3a7fe", "kkk": {"MetaData": {
    "MetaEntry": [{"Key": "status", "Value": "Active"}, {"Key": "first_day_of_week", "Value": "Monday"},
                  {"Key": "default_induction_expiry", "Value": "0"}]}, "RelatedLinks": [], "Tags": [],
                                                                                                "ObjectId": "6cf54386-d81a-eb11-9fb4-281878b13795",
                                                                                                "Type": "Artifice.Web.Data.Entities.Client",
                                                                                                "Name": "Amco Logictics "}}


for k,v in data.items():
    if isinstance(v,dict) and 'MetaData' in v:
        print(f'{k} points to metadata')
```

output

```
kkk points to metadata
```